# I am trying to develop a bootstrap scroll able tabs.which is working perfectly in jsfidle?

Tags: php, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
<style type="text/css">
.wrapper {
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto;
    overflow:hidden;
  padding:5px;
    height:50px;
}

.list {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    min-width:3000px;
    margin-left:12px;
    margin-top:0px;
}

.list li{
  display:table-cell;
    position:relative;
    text-align:center;
    cursor:grab;
    cursor:-webkit-grab;
    color:#efefef;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

.scroller {
  text-align:center;
  cursor:pointer;
  display:none;
  padding:7px;
  padding-top:11px;
  white-space:no-wrap;
  vertical-align:middle;
  background-color:#fff;
}

.scroller-right{
  float:right;
}

.scroller-left {
  float:left;
}
</style>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/roshan1985/js10kb56/

This is working in jsfidle but when i place in my webpage its not working at all.i try to change the css display none. but still same problem coming if anyone face similar kind of problem please share your answer?

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Have you made sure you have the JQuery library linked properly?

Comment: In slider i m using two arrow mark right side and left side to move the tab. cannot see that arrow marks.but when you see my jsfidle link you can see that arrow mark and its working fine.i do not have any problem in jquery or bootstrap. i think that display none in css giving trouble but i do not knw how to solve it

Comment: provide your html also

Comment: <div class="container">
  <div class="scroller scroller-left"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></div>
  <div class="scroller scroller-right"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs list" id="myTab">
      <li class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#profile">Profile</a></li>
      <li><a href="#messages">Messages</a></li>
      <li><a href="#settings">Settings</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tab4</a></li>
     
    
      
 
  </ul>
  </div>
</div>